# Iris Data Set in R

Tags: r, indexing

I am looking at the classic data set called iris in R that contains information for 4 traits for three species. I would like to use the pairs function to plot only 2 traits for all three species. The command to plot all 4 traits for all three species is :

```
pairs(iris[1:4], main="Edgar Anderson's Iris Data", font.main=4, pch=19)
```

I only want to plot for example the first two traits, Sepal Length and Sepal Width for all three species. I tried :

```
pairs(iris[1:2], main="Edgar Anderson's Iris Data", font.main=4, pch=19)
```

But that only gives me one plot for each trait and I need three plots for sepal length and three for sepal width. Could someone help me index the data set correctly to get what I am looking for ?

Thanks!

Comment: Your question will be easier to read (and answer!) if you present code as code. Just add a newline and then four spaces in front of every code sample that you show.

Answer (score 0):

You need to subset your data before applying the `pairs` function:

```
for(spec in unique(iris$Species)) 
     pairs(subset(iris, Species == spec)[,1:2], main=spec, font.main=4, pch=19)
```

Will give you 3 pairplots as desired. Binding them together is not easy, as `pairs` uses `par(mfrow)` internally already (which would be used to arrange the plots side-by-side).